# Webdriver: close web driver only if test is successful

Tags: java, selenium, junit, webdriver, junit4

Webdriver: close web driver only if test is successful.

Is there a way to check test results in `@After` method?

```
public class FooTest {
    private WebDriver webDriver;

    @Test
    public void testFoo() {

    }

    @After
    public void cleanUp() {

        if (isTestSuccess()) {  // How?
           webDriver.close();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Junit, you can pass the `Scenario` parameter to the tear down method:

```
@After
public void cleanUp(Scenario scenario) {

    if (!scenario.isFailed()) {  
       webDriver.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. like to do the same for TestRule. But the after() method in TestRule does not take Scenario as parameter. Is there a way?

Comment: Sorry, don't know. I haven't used TestRule.